# How to vertical align this nav bar?

Tags: html, css

So I have successfully spaced the text in my LI elements from a help from a few SOF members :)

My last issue is trying to vertically center my navbar in its parent container, as well as stop the page elements from breaking when you zoom in or out.

Also, is there a way I can make the page content resize if the person has a smaller browser resolution?

HTML:

```
<div class="h_headerbar">
   <div class="h_navbar">
       <nav>
          <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Publishing</a></li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background-color:#565656;
}
.h_headerbar{
width:100%;
background-color:black;
height:125px;
}
.h_navbar{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.h_navbar li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:35px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    border:3px solid #111;
    margin:0px 25px 0px 25px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.h_navbar li:hover{
background-color:#191919;
}
.h_navbar a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:table-cell;
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100px;
    height:35px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wjur4/)

Comment: The cleanest way to vertically center elements is to apply equal padding/margins above and below the element you wish to center, rather than specifying a height on the parent container and trying to shoehorn the content in. 

Pages tend to perform a lot better across the board if you allow the layout to be dictated (up to a point) by the content. It's a principle of responsive web design that translates to desktop designs as well as mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care backward compatibility in IE6&7, you could add:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

to the container div style.